# How do I programmatically clear the selection of a SelectableText.rich in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, setstate, richtext, textselection

I am working with the SelectableText.rich widget in Flutter, and I am trying to figure out how to programmatically clear the user's selection (i.e. when they tap another part of the screen).

I have a pretty straightforward setup, with my SelectableText like so (as a stateless widget within a stateful parent):

```
return SelectableText.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: doc.allSpans
        .map(
          (e) => TextSpan(
            text: e.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: e.style.contains("bold") ? FontWeight.bold : null,
              fontStyle:
                  e.style.contains("italic") ? FontStyle.italic : null,
              decoration: e.style.contains("underline")
                  ? TextDecoration.underline
                  : null,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList(),
  ),
  onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,
  enableInteractiveSelection: selectionEnabled,
);
```

I've tried enabling/disabling the "enableInteractiveSelection" field, as well as replacing the entire SelectableText widget and then swapping back to try and reload it fresh. With the latter, replacing it with a Container() did clear the selection but I had to put it on a quick but noticeable delay, making the screen flicker oddly.

Replacing it with another identical SelectableText in this same way didn't clear the selection at all.

I might be out of luck and there is no straightforward way to do this, but if anyone has any ideas that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no API built in to SelectableText for this.

As a workaround, you can replace your SelectableText's key when you no longer want the selection.

Below is a functional example of this that you can try out in DartPad. When the example is ran, you'll see that if you select text and then tap outside of the selected text area, the selection highlight will remain. But if you tap the button, it'll be removed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget();

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _index = 0; // you could use a uuid here for a unique key every iteration
  
  Key _getKey() => Key('selectable-text-$_index');
  
  void _removeSelection() => setState(() => _index++);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SelectableText.rich(
            const TextSpan(
              text: 'Select me! When you tap the button below, I will lose my selection.',
            ),
            key: _getKey(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _removeSelection,
            child: const Text('Remove selection'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```